# dompdf render pdf doesnt work on codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, dompdf

This code works but the resulting file is being opened like HTML for me not as a pdf or download pdf. How can I fix that?

```
<?php
require_once("dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");
//var_dump("dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");
$tiket = $_GET["tiket"];
$file = $this->load->view('admin/report/fm-it-01',$tiket); 

$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
//var_dump($dompdf->load_html($file));
$dompdf->load_html_file($file);
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("sample.pdf"); ?>
```

Comment: Have you tried `$dompdf->load_html($file);` instead? Works for me.

Comment: @Mudshark you should make that an answer, because that is how you would load HTML from a variable.

Comment: @BrianS Just did, and yes, thought so too.

Answer (score 1):

Try `$dompdf->load_html($file);` instead of `$dompdf->load_html_file($file);`